# Regex to match specific non-printable characters on the ASCII table

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I am writing a function that checks if the decimal value of a character is printable, and returns a symbol if it is not printable. On the ASCII table, decimal values 0 to 31 and 127 are non-printable, but I want the symbol returned for these specific decimal values only  (0-8, 11, 12, 16-19,21-31, 127). How can I better my code using regex? I am also willing to learn any optimization you can suggest.

```js
function replaceNonPrintableWithSymbol(character) {
  let noEntrySymbol = "\u26D4";
  let characterDecimalValue = character.charCodeAt();
  let specificNonPrintableValues = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,127];
  let isWithinRange = specificNonPrintableValues.includes(characterDecimalValue);

  return isWithinRange? noEntrySymbol : character;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a character class containing all the characters you want to replace `[\u0000-\u0008, \u000B, \u000C, \u0010-\u0013,\u0015-\u001f, \u007F]` should do it